Run Wilcox.tests across two years for two different places, with multiple subgroups
I want to run wilcox.test to compare Yr1 and Yr2 for each Gear within each Village.
e.g.
Village A Gr1 - Yr1 vs Yr2
Village A Gr2 - Yr1 vs Yr2
Village B Gr1 - Yr1 vs Yr2
My dataframe looks like:
# DF1
Village <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B")
Year <- c("Yr1","Yr1","Yr1","Yr1","Yr1","Yr1","Yr2","Yr2","Yr2","Yr2","Yr2","Yr2" )
Gear <- c("Gr1","Gr3","Gr4","Gr1","Gr2","Gr3","Gr1","Gr3","Gr4","Gr1","Gr2","Gr3" )
Var1 <- c(10,7,8,5,6,6,12,11,10,5,4,3)
DF1 <- data.frame(Village, Year, Gear, Var1)


The code I have been trying (below) works if there all Gear types are present but this is not true with the full data set where Gr2 is only present in one village. Is there a way to code in to skip the comparison where data is missing for one village?
DF1 %>% 
  group_by(Village,Gear) %>% 
  do(w = wilcox.test(Var1~Year, data=., paired=FALSE)) %>% 
  summarise(Village,Gear, Z = w$statistic, p.stat = w$p.value)

I was wondering if using a 'for loop' would work but I am quite new at using R and not sure if this would be the right solution and can't find any examples that quite match this use case - with most examples having multiple columns of variables to test rather than the factors.
